# How to create an Http instance without using constructor DI?

Tags: http, angular, dependency-injection

For some reason, I don't want to use constructor(private http: Http) DI.

Looked at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html

and tried

```
const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
  BaseRequestOptions,
  XHRConnection,
  {
    provide: Http,
    useFactory: (backend, defaultOptions) => new Http(backend, defaultOptions),
    deps: [XHRConnection, BaseRequestOptions]
  }
]);

this.http = injector.get(Http);
```

Error says

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'XHRConnection'(?, ?, ?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'XHRConnection' is decorated with Injectable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `HTTP_PROVIDERS`:

```
const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  XHRConnection,
  {
    provide: Http,
    useFactory: (backend, defaultOptions) => new Http(backend, defaultOptions),
    deps: [XHRConnection, BaseRequestOptions]
  }
]);
```

Comment: HTTP_PROVIDERS is now deprecated. Do you have an example for RC.5+?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it can be as simple as

```
const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
  HTTP_PROVIDERS
]);

this.http = injector.get(Http);
```

Based on Günter Zöchbauer's answer.

Comment: HTTP_PROVIDERS is now deprecated. Do you have an example for RC.5+?