# How to create an Http instance WITHOUT using constructor DI? (RC.5+)

Tags: angular, angular-rc5

I need to get an instance of Http without using Angular2's DI ( constructor(private http: Http) )

The following code was taken from [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209217/how-to-create-an-http-instance-without-using-constructor-di), and it works in Angular2 RC.4 and earlier versions, but not in RC.5+(HTTP_PROVIDERS is no longer available) :

```
const injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
  HTTP_PROVIDERS
]);

this.http = injector.get(Http);
```

There are several questions here on Stackoverflow with different variants of that same code, but none of them works in RC.5+.

Does anybody know of how to perform that same thing in RC.5+?

Comment: What if I show you how to use http in RC5 with DI? would it be fine?

Comment: I already know how to use Http with DI.

Comment: But as HTTP_PROVIDERS is removed, you can't use this way anymore.

Comment: I am aware of that. That is the very reason why I'm asking this. I even specified it in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at the source for [`HttpModule`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0/modules/%40angular/http/src/http_module.ts#L45). You'll see all the providers required to create the `Http`. Most of those providers were what were in the now removed `HTTP_PROVIDERS`

```
export function _createDefaultCookieXSRFStrategy() {
  return new CookieXSRFStrategy();
}

export function httpFactory(xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions): Http {
  return new Http(xhrBackend, requestOptions);
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: Http, useFactory: httpFactory, deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]},
    BrowserXhr,
    {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions},
    {provide: ResponseOptions, useClass: BaseResponseOptions},
    XHRBackend,
    {provide: XSRFStrategy, useFactory: _createDefaultCookieXSRFStrategy},
  ],
})
export class HttpModule {
}
```

Just add everything in the above `providers` to the array you pass to `ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate`.

If your goal is to get the `Http` before bootstrap, there's another little thing you need to take care of, which is the `CookieXSRFStrategy`. It will not work prior to bootstrapping, as it is dependendent on some platform browser stuff. You can just replace it with a noop, as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39454713/2587435)

Comment: This seems to be working (I won't be fully able to test it, since I also need to refactor other things in the app, but at least the app no longer crashes in the browser). I am a bit worried that I will only be able to make GET calls (since that's the default method with BaseRequestOptions), but I'll deal with that later.
As soon as I test it, I will mark your answer as the valid one.
I will also take a look at the source code more often, Thank you for letting me know how you came up with this answer.

Comment: I can't believe it. It works! Thank you very much for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an answer.

You can use **Injector** to get dependency as shown below.

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable,Injector } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class Service{
    constructor(private injector:Injector){}

    display(){

        this.http=this.injector.get(Http);   //<<<<------here the magic happens

        console.log(this.http);
        return this.http.get('user.json').map(res => {return res.json()}).toPromise();
    } 
}
```

If  you still have any doubt, you can check this working plunker made in Angular2.0.0 :  
**https://plnkr.co/edit/eWLB2BaL66pnJ7SC6qAL?p=preview**

Comment: If injectable was available then one would use http at the constructor directly...